# Как на php сделать статус online/offline?

Tags: php, mysql

уже сделана регистриция, авторизация, анкета и её редактирование, список всех пользователей и ещё кое-что. Вопрос: как на php сделать статус online/offline? Хотя б подскажите в какую сторону думать.

Comment: в сторону сессий

Comment: возможно в php можно и так. я не знаю. вот только где храниться эта сессия? обычно для сессий заводят memcahed http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/38261/ в сессии можно хранить данные о последних действиях или времени и на основании этого выставлять online\offline ну это в более глобальном смысле

Answer (score 1):

Я делаю так: при переходе пользователем на любую страницу сайта выполняю запрос к таблице юзеров, в которой есть поле `lastvisittime`, при каждом переходе пользователя на какую либо страницу обновляю это значение текущим значением time(). Проверка он лайн / не он лайн осуществляется выборкой типа

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT lastvisittime FROM users WHERE lastvisittime>". time()-300 ." WHERE userid=".$userid);
if ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$online=true;
}
```

как то так. в таком варианте сессии не нужны.

Comment: чтоб не делать эту лишнюю нагрузку на сервер -> сессии -> memcached или какая-нибудь noSql типа redis

Comment: а вот эта табличка lastvisittime - тип у неё просто time?

Comment: @Кирилл Романтик у нее тип int

@boris я так понял, человек не совсем чтобы знаком с сессиями, для начала можно делать с бд, на самом деле нагрузка не ощущается.

Comment: А если у тебя пользователь не активен, а просто держит страницу открытой, как ты определяешь онлайн он или нет?

Comment: @КириллРомантик, Можно каждые 5 минут пинговаться к сайту, и если страница сайта у него открыта, в БД записывается текущая дата. А дальше просто проверять её, если она на 5 минут меньше чем текущее время, тогда пользователь оффлайн.